# how to add if the statement is true

Tags: python

I have made a basic number guessing python game in which we have a number in mind and the ai will try to guess it but when I ran it , it just asks me the same number. What should I do? I have tried to use many things but it doesn't work.

```py
import random

print("""
      
      Hello there my friend
      I am an AI
      I have been made for a very Specific game
      and i would like you to play
      It is an number guesser
      You will think of a number
      and I will try to guess it
      and you would say higher or lower
      LEts Start
      """)
print("Okk so what is the range?:")
rang = int(input())
print("Lets Start. Say (h) for higher and (l) for Lower and (c) for Correct!")
aig = random.randint(1, rang)
print("Is " + str(aig) + "the number?")
newag = 1
def newter():
     newag  - 1
def fewter():
    newag + 1
while True:
    letter = input()
    if letter == "h":
        fewter()
        print("Is " + str(newag) + "the number?")
    if letter == "l":
        newter()
        print("Is " + str(newag) + "the number?")
    if letter == "c":
        print("Finnally i got that Right")
    else:
        print("Sorry but i cant understand")
```

Comment: `newag - 1` doesn't do anything with the result of the subtraction.

Comment: In your case the two functions are so small and only used once you may as well remove them and replace the call sites with `newag += 1` for `fewter()` and `newag -= 1` for `newter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try in `newter` and `fewter` put `global newag` in the beginning of the function, so it will permanently change the value of newag instead of discarding it after the function.

also you need to change `newag - 1` and `newag + 1` to `newag -= 1` (`newag = newag - 1`) and `newag += 1` (`newag = newag + 1`) to actually change the value, otherwise you are just saying what is newag minus one? and then it gets rid of the result.

Comment: There's no assignments in those functions.

Comment: changed 'assign' to 'change'

Comment: There are no statements that change the values of the variables. They need to change `newag - 1` to `newag -= 1`